# Allow hundreds of TCP clients to connect within a second or two

Tags: c#, sockets, tcp

So with my software, I send a discover broadcast on the network and every "client" that receives that broadcast will connect over TCP to me. With what I have, it seems to work "OK" but I feel like there has to be a better way. What I am seeing is that some TCP connections into my software are refused (I think) because I am currently working on accepting another socket. So with my current version, I can accept a socket around 80% of the time. Sometimes more, but usually around the 80% range. The rest are refused by my software and I dont know why. To me thats unacceptable but I am suck as to improve this number.

Here is a class I use to accept TCP clients and notify my other class about a new socket that has connected:

```
public class AsynchronousSocketListener
{
    // Thread signal.
    public ManualResetEvent allDone = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    public event EventHandler<ErtdRawDataArgs> ClientConnected;

    private string bindingIp;
    public string AddressBind 
    {
        get { return this.bindingIp; } 
        private set { this.bindingIp = value; } 
    }

    private int port;
    public int Port
    {
        get { return this.port; }
        private set { this.port = value; }
    }

    private Socket listener;

    public AsynchronousSocketListener(string bindingIp, int port) 
    {
        this.bindingIp = bindingIp;
        this.port = port;
    }

    protected void OnClientConnected(string data, IPEndPoint clientEP)
    {
        if (this.ClientConnected == null)
            return;

        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            //build args
            ErtdRawDataArgs args = new ErtdRawDataArgs(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(data));
            args.Source = string.Format("{0}:{1}", clientEP.Address.ToString(), clientEP.Port);
            this.ClientConnected(this, args);
        });
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        if (this.listener == null || !this.listener.Connected)
            return;

        this.listener.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
        this.listener.Close();
    }

    public void StartListening() 
    {
        Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            // Data buffer for incoming data.
            byte[] bytes = new Byte[1024];

            // Establish the local endpoint for the socket.
            IPEndPoint localEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(this.bindingIp), this.port);

            // Create a TCP/IP socket.
            listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);

            // Bind the socket to the local endpoint and listen for incoming connections.
            try
            {
                listener.Bind(localEndPoint);
                int maxConnections = (int)SocketOptionName.MaxConnections;
                listener.Listen(maxConnections);

                while (true)
                {
                    // Set the event to nonsignaled state.
                    allDone.Reset();

                    // Start an asynchronous socket to listen for connections.
                    listener.BeginAccept(
                        new AsyncCallback(AcceptCallback),
                        listener);

                    // Wait until a connection is made before continuing.
                    allDone.WaitOne();
                }

            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
            }
        });
    }

    public void AcceptCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
    {
        // Signal the main thread to continue.
        allDone.Set();

        // Get the socket that handles the client request.
        Socket listener = (Socket) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = listener.EndAccept(ar);

        // Create the state object.
        StateObject state = new StateObject();
        state.workSocket = handler;
        handler.BeginReceive( state.buffer, 0, StateObject.BufferSize, 0,
            new AsyncCallback(ReadCallback), state);
    }

    public void ReadCallback(IAsyncResult ar) 
    {
        String content = String.Empty;

        // Retrieve the state object and the handler socket
        // from the asynchronous state object.
        StateObject state = (StateObject) ar.AsyncState;
        Socket handler = state.workSocket;

        // Read data from the client socket. 
        int bytesRead = handler.EndReceive(ar);

        if (bytesRead > 0) {
            // There  might be more data, so store the data received so far.
            state.sb.Append(Encoding.ASCII.GetString(
                state.buffer,0,bytesRead));

            // Check for end-of-file tag. If it is not there, read 
            // more data.
            content = state.sb.ToString();
            OnClientConnected(content, handler.RemoteEndPoint as IPEndPoint);

            //close socket
            handler.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            handler.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Is there any way to improve this code or is there something completely different all together to improve my results of accepting TCP connections at about the same time?

Comment: You use of async accept is not right: You are waiting for it to complete. You could just have gone synchronous instead. By waiting on an event you get the worst of both worlds and nothing good.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<s>Well, you have a period of time between when you accept a connection and when the connection is "made" before you can accept another connection.  Using things like wait handles is probably fairly slow.</s>

After re-reading your code, conceptually the point at which you can accept another connection is when you've called `EndAccept`. It appears that you're setting the event before you call `EndAccept` which means `BeginAccept` can be called before the `EndAccept` and that another connection can be accepted before the previous had `EndAccept` called.  I don't know if that's an issue--as far as I can tell, that's legal.  But, you can simplify your code to avoid the events and simply chain the next BeginAccept during the current accept and ensure `EndAccept` is called before the next `BeginAccept`

What I do is chain the next accept from within the current accept.  For example:

```
listener = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
listener.Bind(new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 62000));
listener.Listen(1000);
listener.BeginAccept(OnAccept, listener);

private void OnAccept(IAsyncResult ar)
{
    Socket listener = (Socket)ar.AsyncState;
    Socket socket = listener.EndAccept(ar);
    listener.BeginAccept(OnAccept, listener);
    socket.BeginReceive(new byte[10], 0, 10, 0, (arReceive) => socket.EndReceive(arReceive), null);
}
```

of course, i'm using `BeginAcceptSocket` here; but the concept would be the same with `BeginAccept`...

This frees you from having to start a new `Task`, frees from creating wait handles which are about 50-times slower that `lock` because they are cross-process<s>--which frees you from having a "huge" pause between accepts</s>.

Comment: Im not the best with sockets, so I dont quite get exactly what you are saying. Mind adding more detail to your example or even us my example to explain what you mean?